# If you have 5 spaces to enter characters, and you can only use capital letters and numbers, how many combinations can you make

Tags: combinatorics

You have 26 CAPITAL letters(ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ) to choose from, 10 numbers(0123456789 to choose from, and 5 spaces to enter those characters. You are allowed to repeat numbers and letters. How many combinations are there?

Comment: What have you tried?  What techniques are available to you to figure this out?  Where are you stuck?  Please **edit the question** to provide this information.  Questions that show no evidence of any independent effort to reach a solution are not well received here.

Comment: $36^5$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: **Hint:**  How many choices are there for each position?